# enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i] IndexError: list index out of range, Black Screen

Tags: python

I started to Use Python for Almost a Week. I'm Creating a Game and its name is "Space Invaders". I'm trying to add more Enemies instead of One. I'm using PyGame. Python Version 3.8.7. I have 2 problems. First: When I run the Python File in Terminal I only get a Black Screen. Second: When I Close the window I get this Error. `enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i] IndexError: list index out of range`
Here's the Full Code:

```
    import pygame
import math
import random


# Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))


# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')
icon = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Utente/Downloads/ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerimg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Utente/Downloads/battleship.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

# Enemy
enemyimg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 6

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
 enemyimg.append(pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Utente/Downloads/alien-ufo-pixelated-game-shape.png'))
enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 735))
enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
enemyX_change.append(0.3)
enemyY_change.append(40)

# Bullet

# Ready - You can't see the bullet on the screen
# Fire - The bullet is currently moving

bulletimg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Utente/Downloads/bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 1
bullet_state = "ready"

Score = 0

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))

def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyimg[i], (x, y))

def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletimg, (x + 16, y + 10))


def isCollision(enemyX,enemyY,bulletX,bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False
# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

    # RGB = Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
             if bullet_state == "ready":
                     # Get the current x coordinate of the spaceship
                     bulletX = playerX
                     fire_bullet(bulletX,bulletY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
         if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    # 5 = 5 + -0.1 -> 5 = 5 - 0.1
    # 5 = 5 + 0.1

    # Checking For Boundaries Of Spaceship So It Doesn't Go Out Of Bounds
    playerX += playerX_change

    if playerX <=0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >=736:
        playerX = 736


# Enemy Movement
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
    if enemyX[i] <=0:
        enemyX_change[i] = 0.2
        enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
    elif enemyX[i] >=736:
        enemyX_change[i] = -0.2
        enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

    # Collision
    collision = isCollision(enemyX[i] ,enemyY[i] ,bulletX,bulletY  )
    if collision:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"
        Score += 1
        print(Score)
        enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 735)
        enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)

    enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)


    # Bullet Movement
    if bulletY <=0 :
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state == "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change    
    
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: the indentation problem after `enemyimg.append (pygame.image.load ('C: /Users/Utente/Downloads/alien-ufo-pixelated-game-shape.png'))` is that on the post or is it also in your code?

Comment: It's also on the Code

Comment: maybe change the indentation to add all lines in your "for" because for now you add only one enemy for example while you expect 6 and tell me if it has changed anything

Comment: I Solved The Second Problem! Thanks!

Comment: I Don't Know how to fix the Black Screen

Comment: This is _way_ too much code and not enough debugging effort for a StackOverflow question. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Take a look at these links: [here](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and 
[here](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) for pointers on debugging, and condense your code down to a [mre] that contains the minimum amount of code to reproduce your problem. It's not okay to dump your code here and ask others to debug it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was an error with the score otherwise the indentation was bad but now it's good

```
import pygame
import math
import random


# Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))


# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')
icon = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Utente/Downloads/ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
# Player
playerimg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Utente/Downloads/battleship.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

# Enemy
enemyimg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 6

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
 enemyimg.append(pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Utente/Downloads/alien-ufo-pixelated-game-shape.png'))
 enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 735))
 enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
 enemyX_change.append(0.3)
 enemyY_change.append(40)
# Bullet

# Ready - You can't see the bullet on the screen
# Fire - The bullet is currently moving

bulletimg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Utente/Downloads/bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 1
bullet_state = "ready"


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))

def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyimg[i], (x, y))

def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletimg, (x + 16, y + 10))


def isCollision(enemyX,enemyY,bulletX,bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False
# Game Loop
Score=0
running = True
while running:

    # RGB = Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
             if bullet_state == "ready":
                     # Get the current x coordinate of the spaceship
                     bulletX = playerX
                     fire_bullet(bulletX,bulletY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
         if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    # 5 = 5 + -0.1 -> 5 = 5 - 0.1
    # 5 = 5 + 0.1

    # Checking For Boundaries Of Spaceship So It Doesn't Go Out Of Bounds
    playerX += playerX_change

    if playerX <=0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >=736:
        playerX = 736


    # Enemy Movement
    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <=0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 0.2
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >=736:
            enemyX_change[i] = -0.2
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
    
        # Collision
        collision = isCollision(enemyX[i] ,enemyY[i] ,bulletX,bulletY  )
        if collision:
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = "ready"
            Score += 1
            print(Score)
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 735)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)
    
        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)
    
    
        # Bullet Movement
        if bulletY <=0 :
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = "ready"
    
        if bullet_state == "fire":
            fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
            bulletY -= bulletY_change    
        
        player(playerX, playerY)
        pygame.display.update()
```